# Remote desktop logs in with saved credentials when connecting from one computer but asks for username and password from another

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, windows-server-2000

I have two computers on which I recently installed windows 7 64 bit. Using VPN, they connect to remote network on which there is a Windows Server 2000 SP4 computer. User is supposed to connect to server using remote desktop.

I set same VPN and remote desktop settings on both computers with Windows 7. I set Remote desktop to save connection credentials on both computers, but when I connect to server form one computer, it uses saved credentials and I don't get log-in prompt on server side. On the other computer with same settings using same username and password, I get log-in prompt once the remote desktop connects to server. I even tried copying the .rdp file from the computer on which everything is working fine to the other computer, but that didn't help.

Note that I'm not trying to have both computers connected at the same time.

What is causing this and how do I make the other computer skip windows server 2000 log-in prompt.

Comment: You seem to be doing everything right.  Are there any key differences between the two client computers?  Are they both using the same version of Windows 7?

Comment: @MBraedley  They are both using 64bit ultimate. There are no differences I see which would be interesting. One is Turion based laptop, the other one is Atom based netbook, but all settings related to network are same.

Comment: is one of the 7 computers set to not use legacy ntlm authentication?  that would do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what happened:

Once you select save credentials, you need to connect to the remote computer or the option will not be saved. I had some problems connecting and I thought that save credentials remained checked even if connection is not successful right after selecting that option. It does not.

Once you do connect with save credentials checked, it will remain checked until credentials are manually deleted.

Comment: Yes, just delete the saved credentials and then re-enter, it works. Thanks!